# How to get ASCII code for characters from a text file?

Tags: c, ascii

Update, Hello guys Thank you all for the help, my initial approach was wrong and I did not use ASCII codes at all.
Sorry for the late replay I had a half-day off today and made a new post for the complete code
[there is no errors but the prgram is not working proberly ( this is an update of old post )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547106/there-is-no-errors-but-the-prgram-is-not-working-proberly-this-is-an-update-of)
I wrote the program, and it is working with no errors But it is not giving me the results I wanted

My only problem is when I read a character how to check its ASCII and store it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
 char dictionary[300];
 char ch, temp1, temp2;
 FILE *test;
 test=fopen("HW2.txt","r");
 for(int i=0;i<2000;i+=1)
  { ch=fgetc(test);
    printf("%c",ch);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should never use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you want to compare a character against space (specifically) then compare it against space `' '`. If you want to check for *any* "space" character (including newline or tab) then use one of [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification), like e.g. `isspace`.

Comment: Hi Rashad and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: And now when we can see your code, think about what happens if the input file contains less than 2000 characters? Think about what [`fgetc` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc#Return_value) (and pay attention to what *type* it returns).

Comment: Your code seems quite far from the approach you describe. Please show your code for finding at least one word and simply printing it. Then try the next step for storing the first word you find into a suitable variable (e.g. dictionary). Then please state which of the following concpets you are aware of: arrays, dynamic memory allocation, linked lists, hashing an input.

Comment: thank you guys, I think you are right, comparing to a space directly is way better than converting everything to ASCII code.
I originally studied python before, and in Python I can create an empty list or an empty dictionary and keep adding to it, but I cannot do the same in C language, however it is an assignment for my university class and the text that I'm supposed to read is very short, actually, the professor used the same method in an example ( she assumed that a sentence contains only 300 characters when using a for loop, and counted them.
I will fix and write comments on my program

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<2000;i+=1)` -> `while ((ch=fgetc(test)) != EOF)` And what you intend by *"repeating the prosses and counts how many repetitions we have for each word"* [sic] without providing any type of data structure to hold the prior words seen and the number of times each has been seen is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about plain ASCII, values goes from 0 to 127, your table shoud look like:

```
int dictionary[128] = {0};
```

Regarding your question:

> how to check its ASCII and store it

Consider a `char` being a tiny `int`, they are interchangeable and you don't need any conversion.

`fgetc` wants an `int` in order to handle `EOF`, and trying to read 2000 characters from a file containing less than 2000 bytes can have very bad consequences, to read the whole file:

```
int c;

while ((c = fgetc(test)) != EOF)
{
    if ((c > 0) && (c < 128))
    {
        dictionary[c]++;
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i < 128; i++)
{
    if (dictionary[i] > 0)
    {
        printf("%c appeared %d times\n", i, dictionary[i]);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Rereading, I see that you want to store words, not chars, ok, then it's a bit more difficult but nothing terrible, do not limit yourself to 300 words, use dynamic memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// A struct to hold the words and the
// number of times it appears
struct words
{
    size_t count;
    char *word;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("HW2.txt", "r");
    // Always check the result of fopen 
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    struct words *words = NULL;
    size_t nwords = 0;
    char *word = NULL;
    size_t nchars = 1;
    size_t i;
    int c;

    // while there is text to scan
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isspace(c))
        {
            if (word != NULL)
            {
                // Search the word in the table
                for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++)
                {
                    // Found, increment the counter
                    if (strcmp(word, words[i].word) == 0)
                    {
                        words[i].count++;
                        free(word);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Not found, add the word to the table
                if (i == nwords)
                {
                    struct words *temp;

                    temp = realloc(words, sizeof(*temp) * (nwords + 1));
                    if (temp == NULL)
                    {
                        perror("realloc");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    words = temp;
                    words[nwords].word = word;
                    words[nwords].count = 1;
                    nwords++;
                }
                // Prepare the next word
                word = NULL;
                nchars = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char *temp;

            temp = realloc(word, nchars + 1);
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            word = temp;
            word[nchars - 1] = (char)c;
            word[nchars++] = '\0';
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++)
    {
        printf("%s appeared %zu times\n", words[i].word, words[i].count);
        free(words[i].word);
    }
    free(words);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The effort is commendable, but I suspect it may be a bit outside of what the actual problem is -- though your plain reading of the question wanting *"words"* is dead-on. Somehow I suspect it is the character-count they are after.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin oooops, rerereading you are right, facepalm :)))))

Comment: Chuckling, I can just picture the poor questioner's eyes rolling back in their head when `realloc()` was reached `:)`

Comment: The fact that ASCII defines codes up to 127 does not mean `fgetc` will only return values up to 127, so using `int dictionary[128] = {0};` could result in overflow. `int dictionary[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {0};` is safer (and include `<limits.h>`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil notice that I'm filtering with `if ((c > 0) && (c < 128))`, in theory overflow can't happen.

Answer (score 2):

In C, characters *are*, essentially, their ASCII code (or rather, their `char` or `unsigned char` value). So once you read a character, you *have* its ASCII code already.

However, [`fgetc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) doesn't always return the character it read for you; it may fail, for which reason it returns an `int`, not an `unsigned char`, which will be `-1` in case of failure.

So:

- You need to define an `int` variable to take the result of `fgetc()`.
- If it's not `EOF`, you can cast the result back into a `unsigned char`. That's your character, and it's ASCII value, at the same time.

<sub>PS - I'm ignoring non-ASCII characters, non-Latin languages etc. (But C mostly ignores them in its basic standard library functions too.)</sub>

Comment: FYI, `fgetc` returns either `EOF` or an `unsigned char` value convert to an `int`, not a `char` value.